# Creating and saving snapshots for php v8js

Tags: php, reactjs, v8, serverside-javascript

I have recently started using php-v8js to render server side react and I'd like to increase performance by utilizing snapshots.  Per the php v8js documentation, I see the class for v8Js comes with a createSnapshot method but I would like to compile my source ahead of time to take the strain off of the user.  A php v8js issue said to use `mksnapshot` which is supposed to be a tool that comes with the v8js build, but I cannot find that method anywhere.  How could I find/add this tool?  Is there a grunt helper for this?

Ultimately I would just like to know the best/most performant way of creating these snapshots and passing them off to the server.  Where would I save them?  Should I store them in the database?

Comment: a snapshot is a snapshot regardless of how you make it.   You don't need to worry about the performance of making it, since once it's made, it's good until you change the code you want to be in the snapshot.  You can distribute it or make it on first-run - it probably depends on the size of the generated snapshot which would be more convenient.   Have you read this: https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/09/custom-startup-snapshots.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create your snapshots using:

```
$snapshotBlob = V8Js::createSnapshot($snapshot_code);
```

Then you could store the value of $snapshotBlob in APC Cache, and restore it using:

```
$v8 = new V8Js('PHP', [], [], true, $snapshotBlob);
```